# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type -> passing structure to module

Tags: c, pointers, struct, module

The structure:

```
    #include <gtk/gtk.h>
    #include "db_interface.h"

    struct AddNewEmployee {
    const gchar *fname;
    const gchar *lname;
    };

    void new_emp_get_data(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer add_emp_window)
    {
      struct AddNewEmployee n_e_s; //new employee struct

      <gtk portion removed to clean code> 

      n_e_s.fname=gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(first));
      n_e_s.lname=gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(last));

      db_add_new_emp(&n_e_s); //pass the struct to db_interface to add new employee
    }
```

The header file (db_interface.h)

```
    #ifndef DB_INTERFACE_H
    #define DB_INTERFACE_H

    struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s;
    void db_add_new_emp(struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s);

    #endif
```

The second module (db_interface.c)

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "db_interface.h"

    void db_add_new_emp(struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s)
    {
      printf("Greetings from db_interface, %s\n", n_e_s->fname);
    }
```

When I try to compile the code using GCC, I get the message "error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type". I have tried several different answers I found when others posted their problems with this error, but have yet to find one that works. I copied the code in the function from the db_interface.c module to the original module - the one containing the struct - and it worked fine, so I know my problem lies with sending the structure to the db_interface.c module.

Comment: Note that you have the variable `struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s;` in db_interface.h and the exact same parameter name use in `void db_add_new_emp(struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s)`. This is valid C code and will compile. Some compilers will give you a warning, depending on compiler flags, but this should be avoided since it will most likely lead to runtime errors. You should change either one of the names.

Comment: I agree with @glampert on the fact that having the same name for two variables in different scopes can lead to misleading situations (in your `db_add_new_emp` function, how do you access the global `n_e_s` variable?), while it can be easily avoided by just changing the name of whichever of those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the struct `AddNewEmployee` to db_interface.h and it should compile just fine.
Both .c files need to know how the struct is implemented.

Comment: Since we obviously don't see the whole code here, it is far from certain that the global `struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s;` will never be used. However, I voted + for the first paragraph: the solution is indeed to move the structure to the header file.

Comment: Right, I think I should better change that. But still, if it is a global, then it is missing an `extern`. Which would cause other compiler errors.

Comment: A header file (`.h`) is included by the compiler in every C file that references it. Therefore, placing a declaration in the header file is equivalent as placing the declaration at the top of the C file. I see no need for any `extern` keyword for that. The `extern` keyword is needed whenever you plan to access a variable defined in the current file, from a separately compiled file (different `.o`).

Comment: But if you declare a global in a header file and include it in multiple places, such as in this case, you'll get a symbol redefinition, since the variable in not local (static), no?

Comment: That would be the case without the 'include guard': `#ifndef DB_INTERFACE_H`...`#endif`. Therefore, I see no sign that the code as shown has any problem.

Comment: With the include guard or not, the `struct AddNewEmployee *n_e_s ` would exist in more than one .c file, after the #include resolution, and without a static qualifier. Wouldn't that be a global symbol redefinition?

Comment: The include guard is here to actually prevent the code in-between to be included in ANY file but in the first included one, in the event of multiple inclusions. Please read more about [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)s; and then remove the second paragraph of your solution, as it is partially unknown, partially wrong.

Comment: What I meant was that he is including `db_interface.h` on `db_interface.c` and, apparently, on another unknown .c file, of the fist code snippet. In this scenario, wouldn't `*n_e_s` be present on both modules after compilation, regardless of include guards?

Comment: No, since, without the `extern` keyword, those symbols won't exist anymore in any object file. Therefore, they will be offsets, without names, and won't conflict.

Comment: OK, tested myself, you are correct @7heo.tk. But this is not quite clear to me yet. Why isn't the symbol redefined? This has nothing to do with the include guard, has it?

Comment: No, you are right, it has nothing to do with the include guard. The include guard is there to avoid name-collision at compilation if the header is included more than once in a C file (use `gcc -E` to see the C code after pre-processing). The fact that the symbol is not redefined comes from the fact that the symbol name doesn't exist anymore in any object. Therefore, you will have your structure *n* times when including it in each of your *n* objects, but each object will use its own, without any conflict: the names of the structures will not be existing anymore in binary, only their offsets.

Comment: OK, so the `extern` would ensure that only one instance is kept and shared with all objs. It makes sense now. And btw, `gcc -E`, quite useful when you are playing with macros. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, the `extern` would ensure that the *same* **symbol** (careful about the vocabulary here ;) would be used by all the object files, and that would be set at link-time. And yes, `gcc -E` is VERY useful, but not only with macros: it can help to find what is really included before compilation. One last comment: while it is absolutely not sure that the code in the OP is wrong in any way, you were right about it being fishy: even if that has no place in your answer, you should leave a comment to the OP about the global variable definition with the same name as the local one. :)

Comment: Moving it to the .h file seemed to do the trick. Thanks to everyone for your help. One thing: It would not compile when using gchar with the struct in db_interface.h so I had to change everything to const char <name> from const gchar name. This works as I had hoped.